# Hard drive device name on Solaris

Tags: solaris

I need to figure out the hard drive name for a solaris box and it is not clear to me what the device name is.  On linux, it would be something like `/dev/hda` or `/dev/sda`, but on solaris I am getting a bit lost in the partitions and what the device is called.  I think that entries like `/dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0` are the partitions, how is the whole hard drive referenced?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

/dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0 means Controller 0, SCSI target (ID) 0, and s means Slice (partition) 0.

Typically, by convention, s2 is the entire disk. This partition overlaps with the other partitions.

prtvtoc /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0 will show you the partition table for the disk, to make sure.

Comment: thanks.  I found this also.

http://initialprogramload.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-solaris-disk-device-names-work.html

Comment: Indeed! The real fun is when you start trying to translate the REAL device names. Do an 'ls -l /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0' and look at the hideous path through the "real" device tree. Once upon a time I could translate that for specific CPU/IO boards in larger servers. Uuuuugly!

Answer (score 3):

If you run Solaris on non SPARC hardware and don't use EFI, the whole hard drive is not `c0t0d0s2` but `c0t0d0p0`, `s2` is in that case just the Solaris primary partition.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to do to the whole disk? Look at the EXAMPLES section of the man page for the command in question to see how much of a disk name the command requires.

zpool doesn't require a partition, as in: c0t0d0
newfs does: c0t0d0s0
dd would use the whole disk partition: c0t0d0s2

Note: s2 as the entire disk is just a convention. A root user can use the Solaris format command and change the extent of any of the partitions.

Answer (score 1):

The comments about slice 2 are only correct for drives with an SMI label.

If the drive is greater than 1TB, or if the drive has been used for ZFS, the drive will have an EFI label and slice 2 will NOT be the entire disk. With an EFI label, slice 2 is "just another slice". You would then refer to the whole disk by using the device name without a slice, e.g. c0t0d0.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types for disk label, one is SMI(vtoc), the other is GPT(EFI).

On X86 platform and the disk is SMI labeled(default behavior):
cXtXdXp0 is the whole physical disk
cXtXdXp1-cXtXdXp4 are primary partitions, included the solaris partitions.

cXtXdXs0-cXtXdXs8 are the partitions(slices) of the activate Solaris partitions.
cXtXdXs2 is the whole activate Solaris partition, maybe not the whole disk.

Hope I am clear.

/Meng

Answer (score 0):

C0 - Controller
T0 - Target
D0 - Disk
S- - Slice

Answer (score -2):

c0t0d0s0 *is* the entire drive. The breakdown is:

/dev/[r]dsk/c **C** t **A** d0s **S**

...where **C** is the controller number, **A** is the SCSI address, and **S** is the "slice". Slice 0 is the whole disk; the other slices are the partition numbers.

See [this](http://www.washington.edu/R870/DevicesDrivers.html) for more info.

Answer (score -2):

cXtYdZs2 is the whole drive. period.